# HttpUrlConnection reuse strategy. Should I connect and disconnect every time I need to get data?

Tags: java, http

Let us say we have the following two URLs

1. https://builds.apache.org
2. https://builds.apache.org/api/json

Can I re-use a connection that I have received for the 1st URL to retrieve the content from 2nd URL?

Comment: Yes, because the server and the protocol are the same.

Comment: @Robert so I just open up a new connection to this URLs and disconnect?